# bookmarklet to swap URL with URL/directory

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet (something I've never done) that will read the URL and check if it ends with "/directory". If it does, I want to remove "/directory". If it doesn't, I want to add it.

I'm using the following to successfully append the directory to the URL, but I don't know how to check if it's already there or delete it if it is.

> javascript: window.location = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + '/directory';

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
var URL = window.location.href; window.location.href = /\/directory$/.test(URL) ? URL.replace(/\/directory$/, '') : URL + '/directory';
```

Checks if the url ends with `/directory` if does, removes it, else adds it.